# Turn off 4g on iphone 4s

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to turn off the 4g so I can use 3g on my iphone 4s? I am going to be in a area that has very poor 4g and decent 3g. I am using ios 7. Unfortunately the toggle to turn off 4g in settings, cellular is missing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think that I understand your problem/question. To my knowledge the 4S does not support 4G/LTE ??

Comment: AT&T calls their HSPA+ network 4G http://www.businessinsider.com/iphone-4s-att-4g-2012-3

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. I understand it would help a lot in your case.
There might be a jailbreak-tweak, but since my iPhone isn't jailbroken I cannot give you the right repo or even tweakname.

The carrier has updated your 3G switch to a 4G switch when they started to support 4G.